# Hosting Houdini sample on Codepen

Tags: codepen, houdini

I would like to host Houdini API sample (with Paint Worklet) on Codepen.
But it doesn't work. It works on my website with HTTPS.

https://github.com/benoitdelorme/houdini-sample/tree/master/paint-worklet.

Comment: Hi Ben and welcome to SO, could it be due to CORS (Cross-Origin)?

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome!  Pro tip: Please look at the tag meanings before posting, "Houdini" is for the procedural 3D animation software